# Display string if null value in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, html-table, where-clause

I have the following table which displays the results of a match and the selections for that match for the signed in user. I want to display a text value in the selection.winner and selection.value columns when there is no related record found in the database but I am unsure how to do this. My code is as follows:

```
<% Fixture.where(:weekno => @gameweek.number).each do |fixture| %> 
  <tr>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td>
        <td width="10"><%= fixture.date.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
        <td width="80"><%= fixture.home_team %></td> 
        <td width="10">Vs.</td>
        <td width="80"><%= fixture.away_team %></td>
        <td width="10"><%= fixture.result %></td>
        <% Selection.where(:userid => current_user.id, :fixtureno => fixture.id).each do |selection| %>       
            <td width="10"><%= selection.winner %></td>       
            <td width="10"><%= selection.value %></td>  
        <% end %>   
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the results of the `Selection` lookup into a variable and test against that:

```
<% user_selections = Selection.where(:userid => current_user.id, :fixtureno => fixture.id) %>
<% if user_selections.empty? %>
  <td>You have no selections for this match.</td>
<% else %>
  <% user_selections.each do |selection| %>
    <td width="10"><%= selection.winner %></td>       
    <td width="10"><%= selection.value %></td>  
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've put a `<%` and `%>` on each line because I think it is clearer. You could just use one for each block of code though, for example:

```
<% else 
  user_selections.each do |selection| %>
```

I'm not sure how many user selections you have for a particular fixture but this will find them all so if there's loads you'll get them all which will cause poor performance AND a massive row in your table. You know your data better than me though, maybe there's a limit on user selections.

Comment: Hey Shadwell thanks alot for your help this has solved my problem :) I intend to have only 1 selection per user per gameweek so this should not be a problem although thanks for the heads up :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to display any string if the database field is nil??
If yes you can use,

```
<%= selection.winner || 'string' %>
<%= selection.value || 'string' %>
```

Comment: you would be better in some cases overloading the accessors in the model, so you don't have to repeat this logic in every view you want to display the "default" value.

Comment: I have tried the code snippet above but it doesnt seem to be working as the columns are showing up blank